# ImportError: No module named pyflakes

Tags: python, vim

This error occurred when I typed "vim FILENAME.py" in iTerm.

My screen looked like this every time I tried to add make .py

Screen shot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tadtiqqwc80vou6/%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202014-11-03%20%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%884.08.21.png?dl=0

I've tried to type "git submodule init && git submodule update" in pyflakes-vim but it did't work.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance!

*I'm using python 2.7

Comment: It means what you think it means; the pyflakes module is not installed.

Answer (score 4):

Run `pip install pyflakes` to install pyflakes first.